# Unable to start debugging on the web server using visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

I set up a website in IIS. I am using IIS 7.5. I tried to debug my application from
visual studio 2012 and got the error message below.

"Unable to start debugging on the web
server. You do not have permissions to 
debug the wen server process. You need
to either be running as the same account
as the web server, or have administrator
privilege"

If I run visual studio as an administrator I am fine and this error goes away. I get this 
error If I don't run it as an administrator.

I want to be able to click on visual studio and run it directly without right clicking and running as an administrator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What finally got mine working was on a new machine...we are still using VS2012.

I had to Add and set theuser IIS_IUSRS in my IIs to full control, locally.

- In IIs, right click on website > Select Edit Permissions > Security
- If you see iis_iusrs, then set to Full.
- If not, Change location to your local machine, 
  then select Edit > Add, and type iis_iusrs (yes without an 'e').
  And select that user, and give them Full access.

Also add the iis_isur + perm to the local project folder(s), where IIs is pointed to.

And lastly, had to run VS as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from a shortcut on the desktop then do the following  -

1) Right click on the shortcut and select "properties"

2) Make sure you are on the "Shortcut" tab and click on "Advanced"

3) Tick "Run as Administrator" and then "OK" out of it.